# App to restart after suspend|hibernate - defined in Upstart?

Tags: suspend-resume, upstart

I want an app to re-start (XBMC, but I failed with Firefox and Krusader doing this, too), after the PC wakes from suspend or hibernate. I want to write a script, which runs at the same conditions, and checks the network I am connected to, and execute.( mount my NFS)
I tried with

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_RestartXBMC
sudo chmod a+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_RestartXBMC
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_RestartXBMC
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    thaw)
       killall -9 xbmc.bin ;;
       sleep 5 ;;
       /usr/bin/xbmc ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

But XBMC will not start ( Firefox and Krusader, too)
So, I want to define an upstart script, that will execute after system resume (from hibernate or sleep) I want to be something like

```
start on xxxxx (xxx should be start from hibernate or sleep)
```

Dont if it is possible to make something like that, anf if so how to define correctly the xxxxx condition

```
start on system resume ????
start on system thaw ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My knowledge of Upstart is limited but according to the [Upstart FAQ](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/faq.html#replace-acpid) you have to rely on gnome-powermanager emitting an event that Upstart can act upon.

I do not know if gnome-pm currently uses libupstart but I'm sure this could be done by adding an upstart emit event to the sleep.d scripts that Upstart would react to.

Actually I wonder if your sleep.d script resume problems are related to running as root instead of user, this will affect [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/UnprivilegedUsers) too. You can check *pm-suspend.log* with *Log File Viewer* for errors.

Comment: So, what kind of permission combination do you propose to set the script?